# VPATH is not working when used as target specific values

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need pointing what I'm missing about makefiles. For given makefile:

```
VPATH=
targ1: VPATH=src
targ1: targ2

targ2: targ2
    echo $(VPATH)
```

and empty src direcotry, every time calling "make targ1" I get as expected:

```
echo src
src
```

since there is not file targ2 in makefile directory and in src direcotry targ2 needs to be updated.

But the problem is that even when I create targ2 file in src directory targ2 is updated every time of calling 'make targ1'. In that case VPATH is not working as expected.

> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory; however, make uses VPATH as a search list for both prerequisites and targets of rules.

Howewer problem does not occure when I set VPATH in global scope:

```
VPATH=src
targ1: VPATH=src
targ1: targ2

targ2: targ2
    echo $(VPATH)
```

Result is: make: Nothing to be done for 'targ1'.

Why there is such difference?

Answer (score 0):

> As with automatic variables, [target-specific] values are only available within
>   the context of a target’s recipe...

So in your first example, the value you gave to `VPATH` is *not* available to Make to find the prerequisite `targ2`.

Comment: That's true, but does it mean that makefile searches all files at the begining of invocation?